# Hash table of procedures in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, lambda

I'm working on making a hash table in racket which associates function names with the procedures they represent.  So far I have

> ```
> (define *function-table* (make-hash))
> (define (f-get key)
>    (hash-ref *function-table* key))
> (define (f-put! key value)
>   (hash-set! *function-table* key value))
> ;;and then to initialize it with a few functions
> (for-each (lambda (fn) (f-put! fn (lambda (fn args) ((fn) args)))) (list abs +))
> ```

So I want it to work such that I can make a call like

> ((f-get +) 1 2)

and get back 3, however the current error I get is:

> application: not a procedure;
>    expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
>     given: 1
>     arguments...: [none]

I'm pretty sure that the problem is with how I initialized the table.  Checking with drracket, the values in it are procedures, but I have no idea what they do, and I suspect it's not what I want them to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hash table should be a map from symbols `'+` to functions `+`. Your code appears to be attempting to get the function by looking up the function by its function in the hash table rather than by the symbol `'+`.

Use:

```
(for-each f-put! '(abs +) (list abs +))
```

And then get the function with:

```
((f-get '+) 1 2)
```